# Scraping and saving tripadvisor reviews - using beautifulsoup, get_text() on python 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Happy sunday here !

Disclaimer: Im pretty noob to python (only two weeks learning the ropes).

Right so I have build a little piece of code using beautifulsoup to scrap reviews content from a tripadvisor page and save it to a text file.

My issue is that when I print the results, all the reviews appear. However, when I try to save it to a local text file, only the first review is saved.

Here is the piece of code I have so far :

```
#prompt for URL of the page to scrap
print "                                Paste url here"
importurl = raw_input()
print "                                Import of:"
print "                                %s " %importurl
#convert the page into a soup
r = requests.get(importurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
#look for the partial entry of the review
resultsoup = soup.find_all("p", {"class" : "partial_entry"})
#save the reviews to a test text file locally
for review in resultsoup:
    review_list = review.get_text()
    print review_list
    with open('testreview.txt', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(unidecode(review_list))
```

Comment: what is `new_entry`?

Comment: Well spotted, broken piece of code ! it was meant to be review_list!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rewrite the file on every iteration of the loop. Move the context manager to the before the loop:

```
with open('testreview.txt', 'w') as fid: 
    for review in resultsoup:
        review_list = review.get_text()
        fid.write(unidecode(review_list))
```

Comment: Thats awesome, thanks for explaining that out ! Simple and precise. Really appreciate !